# Who was in Lex Luthor's cabinet?

Tags: dc

The Wikipedia article on [Black Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Lightning) (Jefferson Pierce) mentions that he was appointed to Lex Luthor's cabinet as the Secretary of Education. However, I wasn't able to find out who else held similar positions.

Did Lex Luthor appoint any other notable DC characters to cabinet positions during his presidency? If so, who?

Comment: I wanted to ask the very same question a few weeks ago. Thanks! I think one of Clark Kent's friend (Pete or Jimmy Olsen) was Secretary, or maybe Vice-President

Comment: Pete Ross was his vice president and successor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few others that we know of.

> Presidential appointees
>   The Luthor Cabinet [...]
>   
>   President   Lex Luthor  2001–2003
>   Vice President  Pete Ross   2001–2003
>   Secretary of Defense    Sam Lane    2001–2001
>   Secretary of Education  Jefferson Pierce    2001–2003
>   Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff   Gen. Frank Rock 2001–2003
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Lex Luthor - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_Luthor)</sub>

If this is hard to read the list went as follows: Pete Ross, Sam Lane, Jefferson Pierce, and Frank Rock. These are all the appointments that he made that we know of.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.supermanhomepage.com/comics/who/who-intro.php?topic=luthors-cabinet

Amanda Waller:  Secretary of Metahuman Affairs
Samuel Lane (Lois Lane's father):  Secretary of Defense

He also appointed the former Sgt. Rock as Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff and Cat Grant as his Press Secretary.  (And as mentioned Pete Ross was his VP).